# Android Accessibility Set and Get Edit Text Cursor

Tags: android, android-edittext, accessibility

Is there a way i can set and get the cursor of any edittext using accessibility ?

Using AccessibilityEvent object i could not figure out how to do this but wondered if there is a way i could set and get the cursor using reflection or something .

Comment: Read the documentation for [AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_SELECTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo.html#ACTION_SET_SELECTION).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the current cursor position but can set one.

`info` is the `AccessibilityNodeInfo` for the `EditText` under consideration.

```
 Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
 arguments.putInt(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SELECTION_START_INT, 1);
 arguments.putInt(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SELECTION_END_INT, 2);
 info.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_SELECTION, arguments);
```

Pass the same number as start & end selection int. to set the cursor.